# Знаки вопросов на черном фоне вместо русских символов

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, кодировка

Есть сайт на WordPress. Проблем с русскими символами не было, пока я не начал переделывать вот такой функционал: на одной странице выводится английский алфавит, а ниже - списки компаний, размещенные на сайте. При нажатии на букву в алфавите - скроллится до перечня компаний с названием, начинающихся с этой буквы (этот функционал был встроен в шаблон темы). Вот код:

```
public function build_company_archive( $atts ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $output      = '';
    $companies   = $wpdb->get_col(
        "SELECT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
         LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
         WHERE pm.meta_key = '_company_name'
         AND p.post_status = 'publish'
         AND p.post_type = 'job_listing'
         GROUP BY pm.meta_value
         ORDER BY pm.meta_value"
    );
    $_companies = array();

    foreach ( $companies as $company ) {
        $_companies[ strtoupper( $company[0] ) ][] = $company;
    }

    if ( $atts[ 'show_letters' ] ) {
        $output .= '<div class="company-letters">';

        foreach ( range( 'A', 'Z' ) as $letter ) {
            $output .= '<a href="#' . $letter . '">' . $letter . '</a>';
        }

        $output .= '</div>';
    }

    $output .= '<ul class="companies-overview">';

    foreach ( range( 'A', 'Z' ) as $letter ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_companies[ $letter ] ) )
            continue;

        $output .= '<li class="company-group"><div id="' . $letter . '" class="company-letter">' . $letter . '</div>';
        $output .= '<ul>';

        foreach ( $_companies[ $letter ] as $company_name ) {
            $count = count( get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'job_listing', 'meta_key' => '_company_name', 'meta_value' => $company_name, 'nopaging' => true ) ) );

            $output .= '<li class="company-name"><a href="' . $this->company_url( $company_name ) . '">' . esc_attr( $company_name ) . ' (' . $count . ')</a></li>';
        }

        $output .= '</ul>';
        $output .= '</li>';
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}
```

Я в PHP не силен, но методом тыка я заставил отображаться кампании на русском языке, добавив в код (в двух местах) `'А-Я'` вот как получилось:

```
public function build_company_archive( $atts ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $output      = '';
    $companies   = $wpdb->get_col(
        "SELECT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
         LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
         WHERE pm.meta_key = '_company_name'
         AND p.post_status = 'publish'
         AND p.post_type = 'job_listing'
         GROUP BY pm.meta_value
         ORDER BY pm.meta_value"
    );
    $_companies = array();

    foreach ( $companies as $company ) {
        $_companies[ strtoupper( $company[0] ) ][] = $company;
    }

    if ( $atts[ 'show_letters' ] ) {
        $output .= '<div class="company-letters">';

        foreach ( range( 'A-Z', 'А-Я' ) as $letter ) {
            $output .= '<a href="#' . $letter . '">' . $letter . '</a>';
        }

        $output .= '</div>';
    }

    $output .= '<ul class="companies-overview">';

    foreach ( range( 'A_Z', 'А-Я' ) as $letter ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_companies[ $letter ] ) )
            continue;

        $output .= '<li class="company-group"><div id="' . $letter . '" class="company-letter">' . $letter . '</div>';
        $output .= '<ul>';

        foreach ( $_companies[ $letter ] as $company_name ) {
            $count = count( get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'job_listing', 'meta_key' => '_company_name', 'meta_value' => $company_name, 'nopaging' => true ) ) );

            $output .= '<li class="company-name"><a href="' . $this->company_url( $company_name ) . '">' . esc_attr( $company_name ) . ' (' . $count . ')</a></li>';
        }

        $output .= '</ul>';
        $output .= '</li>';
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}
```

Также после английского алфавита дублируется еще один англ. алфавит, но уже не заглавные буквы, а прописные, так же появились символы `[\]^_`{|}~`, и потом, как я понял, идёт русский алфавит, но он отображается вот так -`�` .

Подскажите как убрать символы `[\]^_`{|}~` и включить нормальный русский алфавит.

Я так понял, что это все дело в кодировке, потому что компании на русском языке не показывались, пока я этот файл не перевёл в кодировку UTF 8. Пробовал менять кодировку на другие, но ничего не получалось. Читал про кодировку базы данных, но этого не хотелось бы делать, так как пишут, что могут быть проблемы потом на всем сайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функцию php `range()` нельзя использовать так, как вам хочется. В [описании](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.range.php) сказано, что "Значения для последовательности знаков ограничены длиной в один символ. Если их длина больше одного, то только первый символ используется". Это означает, что выражение `range('A_Z', 'А-Я')` не работает.

Точнее, php интерпретирует его как `range('A', 'А')`, что приводит к выводу всех символов между английской A и русской А, в том числе и не имеющим отображения. Именно они, а не русские символы выводятся как знаки вопроса на черном фоне.

Попробуйте модифицировать код следующим образом:

```
public function build_company_archive( $atts ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $output      = '';
    $companies   = $wpdb->get_col(
        "SELECT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
         LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
         WHERE pm.meta_key = '_company_name'
         AND p.post_status = 'publish'
         AND p.post_type = 'job_listing'
         GROUP BY pm.meta_value
         ORDER BY pm.meta_value"
    );
    $_companies = array();

    foreach ( $companies as $company ) {
        $_companies[ strtoupper( $company[0] ) ][] = $company;
    }

    if ( $atts[ 'show_letters' ] ) {
        $output .= '<div class="company-letters">';

        foreach ( range( 'A', 'Z' ) as $letter ) {
            $output .= '<a href="#' . $letter . '">' . $letter . '</a>';
        }

        $output .= '</div>';

        $output .= '<div class="company-letters">';

        foreach ( range( 'А', 'Я' ) as $letter ) {
            $output .= '<a href="#' . $letter . '">' . $letter . '</a>';
        }

        $output .= '</div>';
    }

    $output .= '<ul class="companies-overview">';

    foreach ( range( 'A', 'Z' ) as $letter ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_companies[ $letter ] ) )
            continue;

        $output .= '<li class="company-group"><div id="' . $letter . '" class="company-letter">' . $letter . '</div>';
        $output .= '<ul>';

        foreach ( $_companies[ $letter ] as $company_name ) {
            $count = count( get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'job_listing', 'meta_key' => '_company_name', 'meta_value' => $company_name, 'nopaging' => true ) ) );

            $output .= '<li class="company-name"><a href="' . $this->company_url( $company_name ) . '">' . esc_attr( $company_name ) . ' (' . $count . ')</a></li>';
        }

        $output .= '</ul>';
        $output .= '</li>';
    }

    foreach ( range( 'А', 'Я' ) as $letter ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_companies[ $letter ] ) )
            continue;

        $output .= '<li class="company-group"><div id="' . $letter . '" class="company-letter">' . $letter . '</div>';
        $output .= '<ul>';

        foreach ( $_companies[ $letter ] as $company_name ) {
            $count = count( get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'job_listing', 'meta_key' => '_company_name', 'meta_value' => $company_name, 'nopaging' => true ) ) );

            $output .= '<li class="company-name"><a href="' . $this->company_url( $company_name ) . '">' . esc_attr( $company_name ) . ' (' . $count . ')</a></li>';
        }

        $output .= '</ul>';
        $output .= '</li>';
    }


    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: А как мне тогда поступить в данной ситуации, не подскажите? Почитал описание, это получается мне нужно просто перечислить все буквы, которые я хочу взаимодействовать? Например: ('A', 'B' , 'C', 'D', 'E', 'Ф, 'У')....

Comment: Нет, надо дублировать код и использовать дважды range: range ('A', 'Z') а потом range('А, 'Я'). Эта функция принимает только два символа для обозначения интервала.

Comment: Попробовал, в итоге: когда я делаю отдельно range('А, 'Я') то у меня выводиться не все русские буквы, а один вопросик, то есть Вместо алфавита один знак вопроса, а в таблице компаний все компании которые называются кириллицей идут в один столбик, а не разбиваются по первой букве в названии

Comment: Добавил в ответ, как примерно должен выглядеть код.

Comment: Именно так у меня и получилось, видимо так как оно не распознает Кириллицу, оно считает все это за сплошной один символ, по этому компании с кириллицей сводит под одну гребенку. Наверное нужно искать проблему на стороне вопросительного знака, если его переведём в алфавит, то и компании начнут разбиваться по Русским буквам.

Comment: Вам @SeVlad написал, что все файлы должны быть в UTF-8 и без BOM. Проверьте это.

Comment: Ну в этом плагине точно все файлы UTF-8 и без BOM.

Comment: Покажите страницу

Comment: К сожалению, могу показать ее только на исходной теме https://workscout.in/companies/

у меня все тоже самое только вот эта строчка такая: lang="ru-RU" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#"

Comment: Нет, извините, мы тут не медиумы.

Comment: Хорошо, я понял, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

"Знаки вопроса на черном фоне" возникают чаще всего из-за  вывода мультибайтных символов (кириллица) в однобайтной кодировке.
http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.mbstring.php

> пока я этот файл не перевёл в кодировку UTF 8.

В ВП все файлы должны быть в UTF-8 и без BOM.

Comment: Да у него там вообще все подряд выводится.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Это не важно. Важен вывод в мультибайте и ессно кодировка всего и вся - и файлов и сервера